# How to automate 'dpkg-reconfigure locales' with one command?

Tags: locale

In the console to input `dpkg-reconfigure locales`,a gui jump out ,i select `en_HK.UTF-8` as my target ,click enter.

[image]

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
en_HK.UTF-8... done
```

How to automate the whole process into one command ?

Comment: Use debconf's [unattended package installation](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/debconf-doc/debconf.7.en.html#Unattended_Package_Installation)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One command:

```
sudo update-locale LANG=en_HK.UTF-8
```

Easy day **:)**

Comment: update-locale is for updating `/etc/default/locale`. In other words it's something else...

Answer (score 20):

What worked charm for me was a combination between the [@DevRobot's](https://askubuntu.com/a/683412/565017) and the [@Gunnar Hjalmarsson's](https://askubuntu.com/a/683450/565017) answers (run as root). **EDIT**: Added some improvements to avoid annoying errors:

```
update-locale "LANG=en_HK.UTF-8"
locale-gen --purge "en_HK.UTF-8"
dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive locales
```

Another possibility (that works even better) is through the `debconf-utils` utilities and `debconf-set-selections` (run as root):

```
echo "locales locales/default_environment_locale select en_HK.UTF-8" | debconf-set-selections
echo "locales locales/locales_to_be_generated multiselect en_HK.UTF-8 UTF-8" | debconf-set-selections
rm "/etc/locale.gen"
dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive locales
```

Hope this might help.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest:

```
echo "en_HK.UTF-8" | sudo tee -a /etc/locale.gen
sudo locale-gen
```

or if it absolutely has to be "one command":

```
echo "en_HK.UTF-8" | sudo tee -a /etc/locale.gen; sudo locale-gen
```

For an explanation see my answer at https://askubuntu.com/a/1246655/912933

Comment: Worked for me in docker. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to generate a single locale, this should theoretically suffice:

```
echo "locales locales/locales_to_be_generated multiselect en_HK.UTF-8 UTF-8" | debconf-set-selections
dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive locales
```

In practice though, dpkg-reconfigure will fail to generate the locale under Ubuntu 20.04. To workaround, you need an additional command:

```
echo "locales locales/locales_to_be_generated multiselect en_HK.UTF-8 UTF-8" | debconf-set-selections
rm /etc/locale.gen
dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive locales
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably run:

```
sudo locale-gen --purge
```

That regenerates all the locales for your installed languages.

Answer (score 1):

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/pi-aej/43b0a9882780807e01881be3567c4ded) had the solution for me:

```
sudo sed -i '/^#.* en_US.* /s/^#//' /etc/locale.gen
sudo locale-gen
```

Comment: First I reset all, and the activate just 'my' country:
**LOCALE='en-us';**
**sed -i -re "/^[^#]/s/.*/# &/" /etc/locale.gen**;
**sed -i -re "s/^# (${LOCALE})(.*)/\1\2/Ig" /etc/locale.gen**;

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo EDITOR='sed -Ei "
    s|locales/locales_to_be_generated=.+|locales/locales_to_be_generated=\"en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8\"|; 
    s|locales/default_environment_locale=.+|locales/default_environment_locale=\"en_GB.UTF-8\"|
    "' dpkg-reconfigure -f editor locales
```

Related answer: [How do you set a locale non-interactively on Debian/Ubuntu?](https://serverfault.com/a/1114285)