# How to make locale "de_DE.CP1252" available for "dpkg-reconfigure locales"?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, locale

Im using UB 16.04 LTS Server and today a new version of the [locales](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/locales)-package has been released and installed:

```
Start-Date: 2019-02-21  09:44:05
Commandline: /usr/bin/apt-get -y -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold dist-upgrade
Upgrade: [...], locales:amd64 (2.23-0ubuntu10, 2.23-0ubuntu11), [...]
End-Date: 2019-02-21  09:44:45
```

I'm additionally using PostgreSQL 11 with databases relying on the character set `windows-1252` for historical reasons:

```
Name  |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate    |    Ctype     |   Access[...]
------+----------+----------+--------------+--------------+--------------
[...] | postgres | WIN1252  | de_DE.CP1252 | de_DE.CP1252 |
```

To make that available, the following command is used:

```
localedef -f CP1252 -i /usr/share/i18n/locales/de_DE /usr/lib/locale/de_DE.CP1252
```

Using `locale-gen` instead gives the following error:

```
locale-gen de_DE.CP1252
Error: 'de_DE.CP1252' is not a supported language or locale
```

The problem now is that most likely after the new `locales`-package has been installed, my manually added one was removed automatically and access to the databases relying on that locale failed:

```
2019-02-21 09:42:45.109 CET [27039] FATAL:  Datenbank-Locale ist inkompatibel mit Betriebssystem
2019-02-21 09:42:45.109 CET [27039] DETAIL:  Die Datenbank wurde mit LC_COLLATE »de_DE.CP1252« initialisiert, was von setlocale() nicht erkannt wird.
```

From my understanding, all locales which were recognized and enabled by `dpkg-reconfigure locales` have been kept and my custom locale is not listed there.

I guess that app provides all locales from the file `/usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED`? Do I need to add my custom locale there manually as well? Something like the following doesn't seem to work, the new line is not shown:

```
de_DE.CP1252 CP1252
de_DE.UTF-8 UTF-8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, my questions consists of two parts: The ultimate goal is to not need to apply `localedef` more often than necessary and I thought that making my locale recognized by `dpkg-reconfigure locales` solves that. Sadly, that doesn't seem to be the case.

### dpkg-reconfigure locales

The following description is ONLY to make some locale available to `dpkg-reconfigure locales`, it doesn't solve my problem entirely, [which I address in another question](https://serverfault.com/questions/955588/how-to-make-results-of-localedef-survive-dpkg-reconfigure-locales). The directory created by `localedef` `/usr/share/i18n/locales/de_DE /usr/lib/locale/de_DE.CP1252` still gets deleted whenever `dpkg-reconfigure locales` is executed after I did the following described steps.

[Another answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1003961/512299) brought the file `/etc/locale.gen` to my attention, which contains the following docs:

```
# This file lists locales that you wish to have built. You can find a list
# of valid supported locales at /usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED, and you can add
# user defined locales to /usr/local/share/i18n/SUPPORTED. If you change
# this file, you need to rerun locale-gen.
```

So I created `/usr/local/share/i18n/SUPPORTED` with the following entry and `dpkg-reconfigure locales` contained the locale I'm interested in:

```
de_DE.CP1252 CP1252
```

[image]

The file `/etc/locale.gen` afterwards contained my locale as the last line as well:

```
# zu_ZA.UTF-8 UTF-8
de_DE.CP1252 CP1252
```

And with all other lines in that file, disabling my locale using `dpkg-reconfigure locales` changes the line to become a comment as well:

```
# zu_ZA.UTF-8 UTF-8
# de_DE.CP1252 CP1252
```

So, the important thing seems to be making the locale available in the file `/usr/local/share/i18n/SUPPORTED` instead of the package default at `/usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED`.